# Why am I getting the pointer error?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

In the user class I have a pointer "Friendship" to the user class, but when I run the program I get the error - [image]

EDIT: I have figured out why I get the error. "Frinendship is not a pointer, it is a PFRelation, but I still want to access the ProPic and username. How would I do this?

Below is the user class [image]

Below is the Pointer to the user class. [image]

```
func getFriendPic(){

    let imagequery = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    imagequery.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    imagequery.includeKey("Friendship")
    imagequery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {( objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        for object in objects!{
            let userPic = object["ProPic"] as! PFFile
            userPic.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({ (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if(error == nil){
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    self.arrayOfFriends.append(image!)
                    print(self.arrayOfFriends)

                }
               // dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
               //     self.collectionView.reloadData()
               // }
            })

        }
    }
}

func getFriendName(){
    var query = PFQuery(className: "_User")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser()!)
    query.includeKey("Friendship")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        var objectIDs = objects as! [PFObject]

        for i in 0...objectIDs.count-1{
            self.arrayOfFriendsNames.append(objectIDs[i].valueForKey("username") as! String)
            print(self.arrayOfFriendsNames)
        }



    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `include` query parameter doesn't work with `Relation`. Once you retrieved your user, you need to execute a second query to get the Friendship.

Here's an example to retrieve a PFRelation:

```
var relation = user.relationForKey("Friendship")
relation.query().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
  (objects: [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
  if let error = error {
    // There was an error
  } else {
    // objects contains the friendships of the user
  }
}
```

Comment: How would I do that would it look look something like this? http://puu.sh/l7xZg/1c14155426.png

Comment: When I am performing the second query, what is the class name?

Comment: I added an example about how to get `Friendship` from a user.

Comment: In the first line what is user?

Comment: `user` is the user you want to get the data from. In `getFriendPic` it would be the variable `object`. In `getFriendName` it would be `objectIDs[i]`

Comment: Now I am getting an error `fatal error: Can't form Range with end < start`. I put a breakpoint and found out where the error occurs, http://puu.sh/l7zXx/c0dfb99c7c.png. The error occurs after I updated to your code. Any way to fix this?

Comment: I am breakpointing here, http://puu.sh/l7AfT/b852a903b9.png, and the program is not even reaching that point, since the breakpoint does not activate. Why?